# iOS: How to use a UISearchDisplayController to search instead of filter

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchdisplaycontroller

We are building an application with a local database. The home screen has a `UISearchBar` and when the user selects it, he can start typing and search across the contents of our database (much like IMDB's or many other Apps).

Our problem is that we picked a `UISearchDisplayController` to manage the transition of the `UISearchBar` (animate the bar going to the top of the screen, dim the underlaying `UIView`, etc....).

Now, this controller seems to work great to filter the content of a list in memory.
We followed [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view) tutorial and it worked just fine.

But that forces us to run the search on the main thread. If we launch the search in a background thread, i.e. from within this method:

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
```

the all short of crashes arise, since the reload of the `UITableView` happens before / while the search is running.

Any help in either of these options is welcome:

1) Control when the `UISearchDisplayController` invokes the reload data methods.

2) An easy way to simulate this controllers behavior, regarding the transitions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show the relevant code?

Comment: Do you need to support iOS 7?  If not, you may want to use the newer `UISearchController`, which replaces `UISearchDisplayController`.

Comment: Sadly I need to support iOS 7

Answer (score 0):

When running the search on a background thread, are you doing a `dispatch_async` to update the data and reload the table view on the main thread?

Something like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // do stuff that belongs on the main thread
});
```

Comment: Yes I am. The problem is that I CANT control when UISearchDisplayController will reload the table. As soon as filterContentForSearchText ends (even if my block is still running) the table reload starts, Im guessing triggered by the UISearchDisplayController.